# How to restore json schema in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

I've backed the schema using mongo compass in my ubuntu. It's like in the form of

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7bf3090e873c2630ec1fd1"), 
    "fields" : [
        {
            "name" : "_id", 
            "path" : "_id", 
            "count" : NumberInt(1), 
            "types" : [
                {
                    "name" : "ObjectID", 
                    "bsonType" : "ObjectID", 
                    "path" : "_id", 
                    "count" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "values" : [
                        "5b6689bf3059e91432bc7c82"
                    ], 
                    "total_count" : NumberInt(0), 
                    "probability" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "unique" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "has_duplicates" : false
                }
            ],  ...
```

I wanted to import this schema into my mongodb which is present in my windows OS. Could anyone help me with this ? I am having studio 3T installed but it imports the schema as data fields.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to import the schema output from MongoDB Compass to Studio 3T. But within Studio 3T, you can apply schema validation on a new collection by right-clicking on your target database > Add Collection > Validator tab.

MongoDB has documentation on how to apply schema validation rules [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Or could you please tell me how to import the schema using the mongodb compass in windows ?